# Magento 2 - Allow custom shipping method only for onepage checkout customers

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout

is it possible to display a custom shipping method option only to customers using the one page checkout method? In other words I do not want to display my shipping method if the "Ship to multiple addresses" option is selected. I have tried to look to the `collectRates` function to add logic there, but I am not sure how to determine whether one page checkout is being used or not?

Any help or advice would be appreciated.

Code I have for the `collectRates` method:

```
public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
  {

    // Check if postcode is allowed    
    if (!$this->isActive() || !$this->postcodeValidate($request->getDestPostcode()))
    {
        return false;
    }

    $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();
    $shippingPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

    $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

    $method->setCarrier($this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

    $method->setMethod($this->getCarrierCode());
    $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

    $method->setPrice($shippingPrice);
    $method->setCost($shippingPrice);

    $result->append($method);
    return $result;
  }
```

Comment: share the code what you have try.

Comment: @DhirenVasoya - I have added my `collectRates` function that I have with my own postcode check, but I am not sure what I need to look for to determine what checkout type is being used